# is there a way to delay a window.onload event?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a pop-up that automatically appears after a delay. is this possible through javascript? if so how would I implement this into my code?

Here is a link to the code I am working on https://jsfiddle.net/hk2808/7cs4xdmg/

```
function openPopup() {
  window.location.hash = 'openModal';
}

window.onload = openPopup;
```

Comment: See `setTimeout`, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use setTimeout. I would make a more generic function that runs on onload and simply call `openPopup` from there.

Try this:

```js
function openPopup() {
  window.location.hash = 'openModal';

}


function onPageLoad() {
    setTimeout(() => {
    openPopup()
    }, 3000)
}

window.onload = onPageLoad;
```

The popup will load 3 seconds after the onload for example.

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` will do what you are looking to do

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't a way to delay the window onload. You could try to add a lot of images and other things that take a long time to load, but that's not an ideal solution. Instead, you can use `setTimeout` to make code run after a period of time.

```js
setTimeout(function(){
   window.location.hash = 'openModal';
   //or whatever else you want to happen after 1 second
},1000);
//the 1000 means after 1000 miliseconds, or after 1 second.
```

Hope this helps!